# Case insensitivity in nginx

Tags: nginx, configuration

We have several SEO pages like:

```
http://www.example.com/PageOne.html
```

Which we redirect in config like:

```
location = /PageOne.html {
  rewrite ^/(.*) /seo.php?id=1 last;
}
```

Problem is if a user access this page by typing:

```
http://www.example.com/pageone.html
```

"Page Not Found" error is displaying. There are approximate 500+ seo pages. How to write rule for nginx to ignore case sensitivity in url? I want a common solution for all url.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This solved my issue. Sad to say that there is not many articles related to these issues, even nginx doesn't provide user friendly Help/Tutorials.

```
        location ~* ^/-PageOne.html {
             rewrite ^ /seo.php?page_id=1 last;
        }
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

Specifically for `PageOne.html`, you can do the following:

```
location ~ /PageOne.html {
    return 301 http://www.example.com/pageone.html$1;
}
```

If you have multiple URIs which need to be redirected, it appears the best option [is to use Perl](http://dodwell.us/rewrite-uri-to-lowercase-using-nginxperl-nginxlua-or-apache/):

```
location ~ [A-Z] {
  perl 'sub { my $r = shift; $r->internal_redirect(lc($r->uri)); }';
}
```

If you have hundreds of unique URIs which would involve many `location` blocks as above, I'd consider changing your application to handle lowercase URIs rather than expecting the webserver to handle the lowercase conversion.

Comment: Thanks but no! We have more that 500 pages. so this wont fit, I think